# scrape web page pagination with rvest. Pagination path does not appear in the structure

Tags: html, r, screen-scraping, rvest

I need your help with a web scraping problem.
I am trying to scraping news from a website.
But I'm having problems to scraping the number of total paging.

For example on this page I want to scrape this pagination (166). But the pagination path is not in the site structure :

[image]

```
url <- 'https://www.burkina24.com/category/actualite-au-burkina-faso/politique/'

read_html(url) %>%
  html_nodes("#wrapper .nav-links > a") %>%
  html_attr("href") %>% 
  str_trim()


read_html(url) %>%
  html_nodes("#wrapper > #content > .site-content > .container > .row > div > div > div > nav > .nav-links > a") %>%
  html_attr("href") %>% 
  str_trim()
```

I have tried all the nodes but nothing. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The number is clearly there with class .pages. Use the class of the ellipsis as a preceding anchor point and move to the required node with an adjacent sibling combinator.

```
library(rvest)
library(magrittr)

url <- 'https://www.burkina24.com/category/actualite-au-burkina-faso/politique/'

pages <- read_html(url) %>%
  html_node(".dots + .page-numbers") %>% html_text() %>% as.integer()
```

Personally, I would consider looping until there is no match for node with class `next` i.e. `html_node(".next")` returns no match.

Uglier would be something like

```
pages <- read_html(url) %>% html_nodes(".page-numbers:not(.next)") %>% tail(.,1) %>% html_text() %>% as.integer()
```

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need to scrape the number of total pages when you already knew it's 166?
Just loop through 1:166 :

```
url <- 'https://www.burkina24.com/category/actualite-au-burkina-faso/politique/page/'

data <- 
  purrr::map_dfr(
    1:166,
    function(x) {
      articles <- read_html(paste0(url, x)) %>%
        html_nodes(xpath = "//div[@class='posts-lists']/div/article")
      data.frame(
        id = articles %>% html_attr("id"),
        title = articles %>% html_nodes("h2") %>% html_text(),
        link = articles %>% html_nodes("h2 > a") %>% html_attr("href"),
        author = articles %>% html_nodes(xpath = "//a[@rel='author']") %>% html_text()
      )
    }
  )
```

Comment: it's to automate my code. This number may change in the future.
Thank you for your answer.